# Unable to find area between curves

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I was requested to find the area between
$$f(x)=x+6, \,\,g(x)=x^3,\,\, x=-2 \,\text{ and }\, 2y+x=0$$and it is that last expression what takes me out.

In principle I know I must find the intersection points between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, which is not a problem, but I'm failing to express the integral that should be the solution because of that $2y+x=0$. I don't know how to interpret that bound. Can anyone help me understand how I'm supposed to deal with this problem?

Sorry if the problem is silly, I'm fairly new to calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Its an implicite formulation of the function. As normally your y-axis is described by f(x), you can just change the formulation to be explicit.

In more detail:
$$2y+x=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2f(x)+x=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f(x)=-0.5x$$

Now that you have an explicit formulation, you can continue as before.

Answer (score 0):

You are given 4 formulas and you want to find the area, NOT "between" the graphs ("between" implies two things) but bounded by all 4 graphs.   Graphing them, I find that that region has vertices (-1, 0) (the intersection of x= -1 and 2y+ x= 0), (-1, 5) (the intersection of x= -1 and y= x+ 6), (2, 8) (the intersection of y= $x^3$ and y= x+ 6), and ($\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ ,$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$) (the intersection between $y= x^3$ and 2y+ x= 0).

Integrate x+ 6- (x/2)= x/2+ 6 from x= -1 to $x= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, then integrate $x+ 6- x^3$ from $x= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ to x= 2.

Comment: Please check your vertices. I think they should be at $(0,0)$, $(2,8)$, $(-2,4)$, and $(-2,1)$.  Note that $x=-2$ is a boundary, not $x=-1$.